# A monotonicity property for ratios of power means

Tags: probability, probability-theory, integral-inequality

Let $Z$ be any non-degenerate *positive* random variable with pdf $%
g(z)$. Let $a>0$ and $r\neq 0$ denote arbitrary real numbers. Define the "$r$
-mean" of $Z$ shifted by the constant $a$ as follows. (It can be assumed that the
necessary moments are finite.):

$M_{r}(a)=E \left[ (a+Z)^{r}\right] ^\frac{1}{r}=\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty
}(a+z)^{r}g(z)dz\right] ^{1/r}$

Furthermore, for some given $s>0$, define

$k(a)=\dfrac{M_{-1}(a)}{M_{s}(a)}=\dfrac{\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty
}(a+z)^{-1}g(z)dz\right] ^{-1}}{\left[ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty
}(a+z)^{s}g(z)dz\right] ^{1/s}}$

I was able to show that $0<k(a)<1$. However, **it needs to be shown
that $k(a)$ is non-decreasing**, so if $a_{1}<a_{2}$, then $%
k(a_{1})\leq k(a_{2})$. (In other words, $k'(a)\geq 0$. )

I played with specific distributions (lognormal,
uniform, exponential) and it seems to work, but it would be nice to have
some general proof. I'd appreciate any suggestions. (Note: I am just an
economist, not a mathematician. I apologize if I used wrong terminology or I
am unaware of some well-known result.)

Comment: Nice question, and nice effort to present it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the function $k$ is non-decreasing, here is a proof.

The derivative of $E((a+Z)^x)$ with respect to $a$ being $xE((a+Z)^{x-1})$, for every $x$, it suffices to show that, for $s\gt0$,
$$
E((a+Z)^{-2})\,E((a+Z)^{s})\geqslant E((a+Z)^{-1})\,E((a+Z)^{s-1}).
$$
More generally, it happens that, for every positive $X$ such that every moment involved exists,
$$
E(X^{-2})\,E(X^s)\geqslant E(X^{-1})\,E(X^{s-1}).
$$
To prove this, consider a random variable $Y$ independent of $X$ with the same distribution, and integrate the pointwise inequality
$$
(X^{s+1}-Y^{s+1})\,(X-Y)\,X^{-2}\,Y^{-2}\geqslant0.
$$
The expectation of each product $X^aY^b$ being $E(X^a)E(Y^b)=E(X^a)E(X^b)$, one is left with the result that twice the difference between the LHS and the RHS of the inequality one wants to prove, is nonnegative.

Comment: Thank you, @Did! Your trick of introducing another random variable with the same distribution is really nice, and I would have never thought of it. What is even better, this proof can easily be applied to any two exponents s1<s2, not just -1 and s, as in my example. So it seems to me that you proved a much more general result.